# To find maximum value of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

I am new to mathjax so couldn't format so I attached images regarding the problem [this is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgwvi.jpg).

> Find the maximum value of
> $$\left| \sqrt{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13}-\sqrt{x^4+5 x^2+4}\right|$$

And this is my [approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prGsf.jpg).In my approach I found that the equation is of the form $|PA-PB|$ which will be maximum when $P,A,B$ are collinear and $P$ must divide $A,B$ externally
But in this particular problem the points can't be collinear.I tried using derivative but that is big mess .so how to proceed further or any other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're dealing with the absolute value of a function, we can interpret the absolute value as giving us the distance from the function to the $x$ axis *independently* from the direction. In other words, we just want to find the point that's furthest away from the $x$ axis, independently if it's above or below the axis since the distance (absolute value) is all we care about maximizing. With this in mind, it becomes clear that the maximum of $\lvert f(x) \rvert$ has to be either a maximum or a minimum of $f(x)$.

From here it's a fairly straightforward (although lengthy) calculation to find the result. We see that given $f(x) = \sqrt{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13}-\sqrt{x^4+5 x^2+4}$, the extrema points are found when the derivative equals $0$, hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\sqrt{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13}-\sqrt{x^4+5 x^2+4}\right)& = \frac{4x^3-6x-6}{2\sqrt{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13}} - \frac{4x^3 +10x}{2\sqrt{x^4+5 x^2+4}} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
And by equating equation $(1)$ to $0$ we get
$$
\frac{4x^3-6x-6}{2\sqrt{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13}} = \frac{4x^3 +10x}{2\sqrt{x^4+5x^2+4}}
$$
$$
\implies  \frac{\left(2x^3-3x-3\right)^2}{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13} = \frac{\left(2x^3 +5x\right)^2}{x^4+5 x^2+4} 
$$
$$
\implies \left(x^4+5 x^2+4\right)\left(4 x^6 - 12 x^4 - 12 x^3 + 9 x^2 + 18 x + 9\right) = \left(x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13 \right)\left(4 x^6 + 20 x^4 + 25 x^2 \right)
$$
$$
\implies \color{blue}{4 x^{10}} \mathbin{\color{brown}{-}} \color{brown}{12 x^{8}} - 12 x^{7} + 9 x^{6} + 18 x^5 + 9x^4 +  \color{green}{20 x^8} \mathbin{\color{purple}{-}} \color{purple}{60 x^6} - 60 x^5 + 45 x^4 + 90 x^3 + 45 x^2 + 16 x^6 - 48 x^4 - 48 x^3 + 36 x^2 + 72 x + 36 = \color{blue}{4 x^{10}} +  \color{green}{20 x^8} + 25 x^6 \mathbin{\color{brown}{-}} \color{brown}{12 x^{8}}  \mathbin{\color{purple}{-}} \color{purple}{60 x^6} - 75 x^4 -24 x^7 - 120 x^5 - 150 x^3 + 52 x^6 + 260 x^4 + 325 x^2
$$
$$
\implies  12 x^7 - 52 x^6 + 78 x^5 - 179 x^4 + 192 x^3 - 244 x^2 + 72 x + 36 =0
$$
$$
\implies (3 x^2 - 4 x + 6) (4 x^5 - 12 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 33 x^2 + 16 x + 6)=0
$$

This last implication can be verified using long division. Since we can easily show (using the quadratic formula, for example) that the roots of $3 x^2 - 4 x + 6$ are complex, we can rule them out since we're only interested in real solutions. This simplifies our problem to finding the roots of
$$
4 x^5 - 12 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 33 x^2 + 16 x + 6
$$
Unfortunately, this last expression can't be factored any further, and since there isn't a quintic formula to solve for the roots the best we can do is find the roots using numerical methods. By doing so, you find that the real roots are given by
\begin{align}
x_1 &\approx -0.24569\\
x_2 & \approx 0.687122\\
x_3 & \approx 3.44225
\end{align}
However, if we actually plug in $x_2$ into equation $(1)$ we see that we don't get $0$ (in fact it evaluates to approximately $-3.18$). This in fact is a "fake" root, since it is indeed a root of an equation that we obtained later in our procedure to find the roots, but it's not a cero to our derivative, which is what we're interested in. This leaves us with two extrema points of our function $f(x)$: $-0.24569$ and $3.44225$. By evaluating the function $f(x)$ at these points we see that
$$
 \sqrt{(-0.24569)^4-3 (-0.24569)^2-6 (-0.24569)+13}-\sqrt{(-0.24569)^4+5 (-0.24569)^2+4} \approx 1.706
$$
$$
\sqrt{(3.44225)^4-3 (3.44225)^2-6 (3.44225)+13}-\sqrt{(3.44225)^4+5 (3.44225)^2+4} \approx -4.1146
$$
And recalling that, because of the absolute value, we're just interested in the absolute value of these quantities, we see that
$$
\lvert f(3.44225) \rvert = \lvert -4.1146 \rvert = 4.1146 \mathbin{\color{red}{>}} 1.706 = \lvert f(-0.24569) \rvert
$$
And so, we can conclude that $x \approx 3.44225$ is the maximum value.

---

We can visually check our result by plotting the function $\left| \sqrt{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13}-\sqrt{x^4+5 x^2+4}\right|$ as follows

[image]

In conclusion, the final result for the maximum can be stated as

> The maximum value of $\left| \sqrt{x^4-3 x^2-6 x+13}-\sqrt{x^4+5 x^2+4}\right| $ is given by the largest positive root of $4 x^5 - 12 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 33 x^2 + 16 x + 6$ and has an approximate value of $3.44225$.

Comment: Thanks for answering,but can you tell me how did you factorize that 7th degree equation

Comment: @Mathisinteresting, short answer: I [cheated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12+x%5E7+-+52+x%5E6+%2B+78+x%5E5+-+179+x%5E4+%2B+192+x%5E3+-+244+x%5E2+%2B+72+x+%2B+36). There isn't a straightforward way to factor polynomials in general, much less for polynomials of higher degrees. However, if for some reason you happen to stumble upon a factor by some means, you can use [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Polynomial_long_division) to easily show that the proposed factor indeed divides the polynomial, and hence you can factorize the original polynomial.

Comment: ,ok,anyways thanks for answering